# Xcode problems with presenting ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a very annoying problem. I have two View Controllers. I just call them ViewController and SecondViewController. They are NOT linked in an UINavigationController.
When I present the SecondViewController I don't get any error. Now I go back to ViewController. When I call the SecondViewController now, I get two errors:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <ViewController: 0xadd5220>.
```

and

```
*** -[SecondViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16bc1e30
```

I use custom segues, but it's the same when I use modal segues

Can you help me?

Regards
Jannes

Comment: instead of presenting,dismiss view controller....

Comment: I am using StoryboardSegues. I present SecondViewController by typing [self performSegueWithIdentifier...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your SecondViewController instance is gone by the time you go back to your ViewController. Make sure you're instantiating it again before calling it to appear.

Comment: Oh wait.. When I choose Partial Curl as Transition, everything works fine. No errors, no warnings...